# How do I create a pentagon and hexagon using create_line in python tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, geometry, tkinter-canvas

Here is the code I have for drawing a triangle and square in python tkinter canvas using create_lines, how would I use create_lines to create a pentagon and hexagon?

Note: For the pentagon and hexagon, the length and width refer to the total square shaped area the shape is contained within, not the width and length of the sides.

```
    self.x, self.y = 50, 50

def triangle(self):
    width = self.width.get()
    length = self.length.get()
    color = self.color_select.get()

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, (self.x + (int(length) / 2)), (self.y + int(length)), fill = color)

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, (self.x - (int(length) / 2)), (self.y + int(length)), fill = color)

    self.canvas.create_line((self.x - (int(length) / 2)), (self.y + int(length)), (self.x + (int(length) / 2)), (self.y + int(length)), fill = color)

    self.x += 50

def square(self):
    width = self.width.get()
    length = self.length.get()
    color = self.color_select.get()

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + int(width), self.y, fill = color)

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y + int(length), fill = color)
    self.y += int(length)

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + int(width), self.y, fill = color)
    self.x += int(width)

    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y - int(length), fill = color)
    self.y -= int(length)

    self.x += 50

def pentagon(self):
    width = self.width.get()
    length = self.length.get()
    color = self.color_select.get()

def hexagon(self):
    width = self.width.get()
    length = self.length.get()
    color = self.color_select.get()
```

Comment: you will have to use `math.sin()`, `math.cos()` or `math.tan()` to calculate some distances.

Comment: adding to **furas** answer, use [create_polygon](http://http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_polygon-method) and create one entity on the canvas, rather than populating it with mutiple lines

Answer (score 1):

To create a regular polygon from a bounding box, you need to calculate the **side length**, and the **apothem**.
The side length is calculated from the radius (the distance from the center to a vertex)
The Apothem (the distance from the center to the mid-point of a side), is calculated from the side length.
([more here](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonsides.html))

in the following example, the bbox is centered on the center of the polygon created; you can offset it as you please to match your preferred anchoring point.

Given the same bounding box, all polygons are calculated to be inscribed in the same circle - the circumcircle, which is the limit of a polygon when the number of sides tends to infinity, see image below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500


class Point:
    """convenience for point arithmetic"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y


class RegularPolygon:

    def __init__(self, num_sides, bbox_side, x, y):   # x, y are bbox center canvas coordinates
        self.bbox_side = bbox_side
        self.num_sides = num_sides
        self.side_length = None
        self.apothem = None
        self._calc_side_length()
        self.points = [Point(x - self.side_length // 2, y - self.apothem)]
        self._make_points()
        self.lines = []
        self._make_lines()

    def _calc_side_length(self):
        """Side length given the radius (circumradius):
        i/e the distance from the center to a vertex
        """
        self.side_length = 2 * (self.bbox_side // 2) * math.sin(math.pi / self.num_sides)

        # Apothem, i/e distance from the center of the polygon 
        # to the midpoint of any side, given the side length 
        self.apothem = self.side_length / (2 * math.tan(math.pi / self.num_sides))

    def _make_points(self):
        _angle = 2 * math.pi / self.num_sides
        for pdx in range(self.num_sides):
            angle = _angle * pdx
            _x = math.cos(angle) * self.side_length
            _y = math.sin(angle) * self.side_length
            self.points.append(self.points[-1] + Point(_x, _y))

    def _make_lines(self):
        for p0, p1 in zip(self.points[:-1], self.points[1:]):
            self.lines.append((*p0, *p1))

    def draw(self, canvas):
        for line in self.lines:
            canvas.create_line(line)
        # alternatively, use canvas.create_polygon(points coordinates) instead


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()

CENTER = Point(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)

for n_sides in range(3, 12):
    p = RegularPolygon(n_sides, 300, *CENTER)
    p.draw(canvas)


root.mainloop()
```

**Drawing regular polygons from 3 to 12 sides (incl)**

[image]

**Given the same bounding box, all polygons are calculated to be inscribed in the same circle, the circumcircle.**

[image]