# Can't figure out why the pentagon is being drawn incorrectly and not moving over to the right like the other shapes do

Tags: python, tkinter

Each button at the bottom is supposed to draw the given shapes with the parameters on the right. Triangle and square get drawn properly but when trying to draw the pentagon it doesn't touch at the tip and won't move over to the right

[exampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLjpA.jpg)

heres my code:

```
def drawTriangle(self):
    color = self.favorite.get()
    thickness = int(self.widthEntry.get())
    length = int(self.lengthEntry.get())
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x - (length/2), self.y + length, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x -= length/2
    self.y += length
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + length, self.y, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x += length
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x - (length/2), self.y - length, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x -= length/2
    self.y -= length

    self.x += 70

def drawSquare(self):
    color = self.favorite.get()
    thickness = int(self.widthEntry.get())
    length = int(self.lengthEntry.get())
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + length, self.y, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x += length
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y + length, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.y += length
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x - length, self.y, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x -= length
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y - length, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.y -= length

    self.x += 70

def drawPentagon(self):
    color = self.favorite.get()
    thickness = int(self.widthEntry.get())
    length = int(self.lengthEntry.get())
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x - (length/2), self.y + (length/3), fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x -= length/2
    self.y += length/3
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + (length/5), self.y + (length*2/3), fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x += length/5
    self.y += length*2/3
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + (length*4/5), self.y, fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x += length*4/5
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + (length/5), self.y - (length*2/3), fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x += length/5
    self.y -= length*2/3
    self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x - (length/2), self.y - (length/3), fill = color, width = thickness)
    self.x -= length/2
    self.y -= length/3

    self.x += 70
```

EDIT: Wow I'm so stupid. Was a simple math problem. Thanks for the help! I'll make sure I debug more before posting here.

Comment: I guess you haven’t bothered to do any debugging - e.g. what’s the net sum of the things added to self.x?

Comment: This seems like a very simple math/debugging task you can easily do

Comment: You might want to consider implementing this in a completely different manner. Instead of a having separate custom function for each shape, it's possible to create a generic function that could generate any convex [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) base on the number of sides desired and a few other parameters. The easiest way might be by using the angle between each point around the edge and their angle from the center point.

Comment: oh i think it is a simple math task. i never thought of summing the values to make sure they equal 0. thanks ill check on that! FYI im super beginner, sorry i didnt think of that before posting

Comment: look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842453/how-do-i-create-a-pentagon-and-hexagon-using-create-line-in-python-tkinter-canva