# Using a polygon to make a circle of a given radius

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am teaching some children the concept of abstraction. The example I am currently using is generalizing squares, triangles, stars, etc to a polygon.

```
def polygon(l, s, a):
    for i in range(s):
        forward(l)
        left(180 - a)
```

To make a square I would write `polygon(100, 4, 90)` and a triangle `polygon(100, 3, 60)`.

I know python turtle has a function for making circles, but I would like to use my polygon function for making a circle.

Now my question is, how can I use polygon to construct a circle of given radius?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842453/how-do-i-create-a-pentagon-and-hexagon-using-create-line-in-python-tkinter-canva/55844026#55844026) addresses your question - you will need to replace lines with polygon, but this is easily done by stashing the calculated endpoints in a sequence, and calling `canvas.create_polygon` on it, with the option `closed polygon` set to true.

Comment: @Reblochon Maque, No it does not, what I want is the parameters that I should pass to my polygon function so I can make a circle of a given radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have to answer my own question. To make a circle out of polygon I came up with this:

```
def ccircle(radius, precision=100):
    total_internal_angle = 360
    angle = total_internal_angle / precision
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius
    polygon(circumference/precision, precision, 180 - angle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is great! (+1) I would tweak a couple of things if we want to better emulate turtle's own `circle()` method.  The first is that turtle's circles have a default precision of 60 sides once the radius gets to reasonable size.  Second, the angle that turtle's circles start off at is slightly different:

```
from math import pi
from turtle import *

def polygon(length, sides, angle):
    for _ in range(sides):
        forward(length)
        left(180 - angle)

def circle_via_polygon(radius, precision=60):
    total_internal_angle = 360
    angle = total_internal_angle / precision
    circumference = 2 * pi * radius
    left(angle / 2)  # match turtle's circle() method
    polygon(circumference / precision, precision, 180 - angle)
    right(angle / 2)  # ditto

color('blue')
circle(150)  # turtle's own circle()

color('red')
circle_via_polygon(150)  # circle() using polygon()

exitonclick()
```

[image]