# Drawing regular polygons inside each other with specific specing using turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a function that draws regular polygons inside each other as in the attached picture. The size of the polygons' side is defined by the following formula:

```
initial_size = initial_radius*(2*math.sin(360/(2*number_of_angles)))
```

I have two questions: 1. Why when I assign "initial_size" by the above formula my drawing starts in a different direction rather than when I simply assign initial_size = 100 (disregarding the formula)? 2. Can you please provide me with a hint (or any direction) on a way I can draw regular polygons as on the picture (i.e., starting from different points (moving along x-axis) and drawing each polygon inside the other?

[image]

```
import turtle 
import math
turtle.speed(1)

def reg_polygon(number_of_angles, initial_radius):
Q = 180-(180/number_of_angles)/2
turtle.left(Q)    

initial_size = initial_radius*(2*math.sin(360/(2*number_of_angles)))
if number_of_angles>=3:
    sum_angle = 180*(number_of_angles-2)
    angle = sum_angle/number_of_angles
    for i in range(number_of_angles):
        turtle.forward(initial_size)
        turtle.left(180-angle)
elif number_of_angles<3:    
    print("Minimum number of angels should be >=3")

    
for i in range(3,6):
 reg_polygon(i,100) 
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the following code snippet draws; it is not an absolutely perfect reproduction of the gif you posted (some tweaks for the size progression for 3, 4, and 5-gons must be done to avoid the smaller neighbors to touch at some points - i/e the gif maker somewhat cheated!), but it follows mathematical symmetry and perfection.

[image]

The following code has some magic numbers; I may come back to it later, but not at this time. The resources I used to calculate a regular polygon can be found [here](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonsides.html), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842453/how-do-i-create-a-pentagon-and-hexagon-using-create-line-in-python-tkinter-canva/55844026#55844026).

```
import turtle 
import math


def reg_polygon(start_pos, number_of_angles, side):
    interior_angle = (180 * (number_of_angles - 2)) / number_of_angles
    turtle.setheading(180 - interior_angle//2)

    for i in range(number_of_angles):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.left(180 - interior_angle)
    
def reset_start_point():
    global start_pos, startx, starty, initial_size, number_of_angles, side
    startx += 8
    starty -= 0
    initial_size += 8
    number_of_angles += 1
    side = 2 * initial_size * math.sin(math.radians(180/number_of_angles))
    start_pos = startx, starty
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto((startx, starty))
    turtle.pendown()
    
start_pos = startx, starty = 0, 0
number_of_angles = 2
initial_size = 15  # radius
side = 0

while number_of_angles < 21:
    reset_start_point()
    reg_polygon(start_pos, number_of_angles, side)
    
turtle.done()
```